# Android. How to get TimeZone looking like GMT-0X:00?

Tags: android, timezone, gmt

How to output "GMT -0X:00" (X - a number)"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(locale);
// or Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(timezone);
int zoneOffset = cal.get(Calendar.ZONE_OFFSET);

// eg: "-0700"
String timezoneStr = new SimpleDateFormat("Z").format( cal.getTime() );
```

Comment: The output is _+0400_; it suits me.